# Download Firebase data as Excel file or PDF file

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an app where the details about a project from Firebase are displayed in Recyclerview.

[image: App screenshot]

When a user clicks the download button (Red Box), the data of that particular project should be downloaded from the Firebase.

[image: Firebase database of a project]

I searched a lot to get an answer to this. But everyone just telling to download it from Firebase Console.
I know that csv file can be downloaded from Firebase console.
I need this to be downloaded from my app and store it in the local storage of the user.

It will be more helpful if it can be downloaded as an Excel file or PDF.

Comment: What is the problem with [downloading the data through the Realtime Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There is no problem with displaying the data in the app. I need to download the data as a CSV file (Like download report option) and store it in local storage of the user's phone.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime Database does not have an API to download data in CSV format. If you want to provide the data in CSV format to your users, you'll have to download it through the REST API or SDK, and convert it to CSV format in your application code.